# Nested navigation approaches

Tags: navigation

I'm looking for a good way to have primary and secondary navigation. The idea is to have 2-3 big categories and 5-6 small categories for every big category.

I don't want to use nested navigation.

I'm tempted to use the following approach:

```
1 - Big categories using regular horizontal navigation (header)
2 - Dynamic vertical navigation for small categories(right or left)
```

What do you think about this approach? Do you recommend another approach?

Comment: what's the context? Sounds like a website where it's primary vs secondary navigation. Very established pattern.

Comment: It's a web based application for professionnal in the finance industry. Ideally, I would like to only use the vertical menu for navigation with multiple levels but without having the menu expanding.

Comment: When you use absolutes like "I don't want to use nested navigation," it begs the question, what has driven this decision?

Comment: So many questions: What mapping did you do to arrive at a two-level navigation structure? What is preventing you from using nested navigation? What other avenues have you explored? Do you have any sketches that demonstrate your thinking?